# Ruby: Round Down to Nearest Square Number

Tags: ruby

I want to create a class that makes the number round ***down*** to the nearest square number( 1, 4, 9, 16, 25...).

I've tried some other code suggestions but I haven't found anything helpful. I don't know mostly how to get it to the nearest square

```
class Integer
  def down
    #round down to nearest square using self
  end
end

(27).down #=> 25
```

Comment: Homework?  What have you tried?  Is this supposed to handle negative numbers as well?

Comment: `Math.sqrt(num).round`

Comment: @Surya `round` doesn't necessarily go down, and that won't yield a result which is an integer squared.

Comment: @pjs - It doesn't have to go down, the question asks for nearest number hence round works.

Comment: @surya "round **down** to the nearest square number".

Comment: @pjs - I would like the OP to build their answer on the hint. :)

Comment: @Josh You're on the right track.  Take Surya's hint, your knowledge, and square the result.  Please note that around here you're expected to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Josh, maybe the code below can help you. You can put that in a ruby file and then run in the terminal. It will ask for a value and will return the answer.

```rb
class Integer
  def down
    Integer.sqrt(self) ** 2
  end
end

print "Enter a valid number: "
a = gets.to_i
puts a.down
```

Updated thanks to [pjs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2166798/pjs) and [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland).

Comment: No need for the `.to_s.split` and conversion back, `Integer.sqrt` yields an integer...

Comment: True! Thank you!